# Why is Cassandra client failing without epoll in production?

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, kubernetes, nio

When I run my service locally, I get a warning that epoll isn't available, so it's using NIO. Fair enough. When I deploy it in Kubernetes, I get this, which prevents the service from running:

```
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739482458Z 19:09:22.739 WARN  com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil - Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, but epoll is not available. Using NIO instead. 
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739505903Z java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty-transport-native-epoll
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739509966Z  at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739513326Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:269)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739516421Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:64)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739519628Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:33)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739522527Z  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739525253Z  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739528047Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.<clinit>(NettyUtil.java:68)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739530907Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:99)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739533585Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:769)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739544382Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1400)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739547340Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739550134Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739555749Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:280)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739558846Z  at io.getquill.context.cassandra.CassandraSessionContext.<init>(CassandraSessionContext.scala:38)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739562704Z  at io.getquill.CassandraAsyncContext.<init>(CassandraAsyncContext.scala:19)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739565629Z  at io.xxxxxxxxx.platform.db.Datastore.<init>(Datastore.scala:26)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739568481Z  at DatastoreModule.configure(DatastoreModule.scala:22)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739571234Z  at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739574009Z  at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739576726Z  at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739579348Z  at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:177)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739581979Z  at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739584688Z  at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739587416Z  at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739590109Z  at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739592859Z  at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739595643Z  at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739598376Z  at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739600979Z  at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739603649Z  at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739606361Z  at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739609008Z  at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739611618Z  at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739614246Z  at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739616846Z Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to get field ID: DefaultFileRegion.transfered
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739619540Z  at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739624975Z  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739627704Z  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739630403Z  at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739632988Z  at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739635608Z  at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:36)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739638288Z  at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739640937Z  at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:222)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.739643779Z  ... 33 common frames omitted
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902948521Z 19:09:22.902 WARN  i.n.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete() 
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902975391Z java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902979455Z  at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:146)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902982663Z  at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:42)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902985588Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:162)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902988575Z  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:149)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902991374Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902995665Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:488)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.902998584Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.903001524Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:438)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.903004958Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:233)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.903008073Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
2017-03-29T19:09:22.903011054Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How do I:

a) Stop the error; and

b) Make it use epoll if that's more performant than whatever NIO uses otherwise (is it really using `select`?)

Comment: Here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746505/how-to-fix-the-found-nettys-native-epoll-transport-in-the-classpath-but-epoll

Comment: Your problem with epoll is not the culprit. It seems that the epoll library available on your system is not compatible with the one that Netty expects to find (cf. "RuntimeException: failed to get field ID: DefaultFileRegion.transfered"), but the driver can live without it. What is causing your service to fail is the next, totally unrelated NPE. This NPE is being thrown because the channel is null, which is definitely not normal. Please file a bug here so that we can investigate: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/JAVA.

Comment: @adultra I added `"io.netty" % "netty-transport-native-epoll" % "4.1.6.Final" classifier "linux-x86_64"`, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this dependency fixed the problem:

`"io.netty" % "netty-transport-native-epoll" % "4.1.6.Final" classifier "linux-x86_64"`