# Cassandra client cannot connect to cassandra server

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to connect a cassandra client from a kubernetes pod to a cassandra server pod. I first faced this issue:

```
Exception in thread “main” com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: deep-cas-cassandra.deep/10.98.133.169:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [deep-cas-cassandra.deep/10.98.133.169:9042] Cannot connect))
```

Which I solved by changing my client version from 2.9.1 to 3.2.0.
But now I'm getting this Null pointer exception from io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.

This is the client version that I'm using now:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is my cassandra server version:

```
root@deep-cas-cassandra-0:/# cqlsh 10.39.0.1
Connected to cassandra at 10.39.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

This is the error message that I'm getting in my application logs:

```
2018-01-02 20:20:45,957 INFO [main] com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
2018-01-02 20:20:46,424 INFO [main] com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory Using native clock to generate timestamps.
2018-01-02 20:20:46,701 INFO [main] com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
2018-01-02 20:20:47,012 WARN [globalEventExecutor-6-1] io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise An exception was thrown by com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:146)
at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:42)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:161)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:148)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:431)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:240)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any suggestions ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. In particular, update your question with a few links where you did search or describe how you tried to solve it on your own. This show effort and others understand/ can help you better. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Since a tag is kubernetes - may be you hit this one? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3588

Comment: Just another thought: did you set your cluster name correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103047/why-is-cassandra-client-failing-without-epoll-in-production?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746505/how-to-fix-the-found-nettys-native-epoll-transport-in-the-classpath-but-epoll

Comment: i faced same issue with older java version

Comment: You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263302/cassandra-nohostavailableexception-all-hosts-tried-for-query-failed . I had the same error, and the cause could be the same. I'm using Java 8 with spring boot.