# Cassandra :NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax, database-replication, cassandra-3.0

I'm repplication the data from on simplestrategy Cassandra's DB to another one. They have the same keyspace's structure. However, when I ran the command *sstableloader --nodes* appeared the error below. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

**Cassandra's version:** 3.11.10

**Command line:** `# sstableloader --nodes 127.0.0.0 /var/lib/cassandra/loadme/keyspace/table01-5eef6110d04111ebb620bd376a9dc9e9/snapshots/dropped-1624306636002-table01`

**Stacktrace Error:**

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.0:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.0] Cannot connect))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.0:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.0] Cannot connect))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.0:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.0] Cannot connect))
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:93)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.0:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.0] Cannot connect))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Is Cassandra up and running on  127.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, it is. Standard configuration and simplestrategy keyspace.

Comment: What does "netstat -tln | grep 9042"  return, omit qoutes?

Comment: @apesa, this is the command's return:  `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command line you're passing `--nodes 127.0.0.0` but in the netstat output port 9042 (Native Transport) is listening on 127.0.0.1. Try changing your command line to `--nodes 127.0.0.1`

When you get an error `All host(s) tried for query failed` and nodetool indicates your cluster is up and running always make sure the correct ports are bound to your IP or localhost.