# Netty so loading exception when run webflux in a docker container

Tags: docker, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

The application works well in local system, but I when ran it in docker, failed.

The dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-microservice-sample/blob/master/auth-service/Dockerfile).

The following error in console when starts this service in Docker.

```
auth-service        |           ... 185 common frames omitted
auth-service        |   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_transport_native_epoll.so
auth-service        |           at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
auth-service        |           ... 186 common frames omitted
auth-service        |           Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll in java.library.path
auth-service        |                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
auth-service        |                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
auth-service        |                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
auth-service        |                   at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
auth-service        |                   at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
auth-service        |                   at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
auth-service        |                   ... 186 common frames omitted
auth-service        |                   Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll in java.library.path
auth-service        |                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
auth-service        |                           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
auth-service        |                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
auth-service        |                           at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
auth-service        |                           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
auth-service        |                           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
auth-service        |                           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746505/how-to-fix-the-found-nettys-native-epoll-transport-in-the-classpath-but-epoll

Comment: It is similar, thanks. I have to add this dependency or force it using NIO  in Docker?

Comment: @pvpkiran Add the dependency and build a new jar for Docker, the error is disappeared. Thanks.